# Can I backup my Poker Night at the Inventory data for use on other systems? If so, how?

Tags: poker-night-at-the-inventory

Since Poker Night at the Inventory isn't a Steam Cloud game, I want to back up my data for use on my laptop when away from home. Is this possible?

Note: If it helps, I have both Mac and PC systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On PC your save file location is:

```
%HOMEPATH%\Documents\Telltale Games\Poker Night at the Inventory\
```

On MAC your save file location is:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Telltale Games
```